# Print to network printer via command line

Tags: fedora, network-printer

I have an Epson TM-T88V connected via USB to a windows laptop, which is running a print server.

I'd like to be able to print using something along the lines of

`lp -h 10.0.0.225 -d EPSON /path/to/file` but the command just hangs. Any ideas, doesn't have to be lp, I'm not fussy?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Afraid I'm not very familiar with fedora but first thought would be drivers?

Comment: I have a PPD, but I'm unsure how to use it.

Comment: Have you used the lpadmin and lpstat commands to make sure everything is configured correctly?